# Page state navigation not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this state

```
  .state('profile', {
    url: "/profile/:profileId",
    templateUrl: 'templates/profilePages/userProfile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileController'      
  })
  .state('profile.edit', {
    url: "profile/edit/:profileId/:field",
    templateUrl: 'templates/profilePages/edit-pages/edit.html',
    controller: 'ProfileController'      
  })
```

I am trying to navigate by

```
<a href="#/profile/edit/mmm/111" class="ion-edit"></a>
```

Its not navigating to given page and no error in console log  also

Comment: Did I helped you to solve it?

Comment: ahh yet to check...will check it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in you states:

1. Your second state do not start with slash (**/**)
2. In fact, **your second state is a nested state** of the first one (because you are using syntax *parent.child* in state name. Because of that, **the url of the second state MUST be relative to the first state**:

   > something like     **url: "/edit/:field"**, that will match the href: **/profile/mmmmmm/edit/111**
3. As **you parent state (profile) is NOT declared as abstract**, you should include in it's template another `<ui-view>` element in order to display the children state, because otherwise you won't see it, (and I guess that this is not what you expect).

I think you must review [ui-router nested states documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) in detail.

I'm attaching some code, that you can run to see the results.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])


.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $stateProvider
     .state('main', {
    url: "/main",
    template: '<ion-content class="has-header">' + 
                  '<a href="#/profile/mmm"                              > Profile       </a>' + 
                  '</br></br>' + 
                  '<a href="#/profile/mmmmmm/edit/111"  class="ion-edit"> Edit profile  </a>' + 
              '</ion-content>'
  })
  
     .state('profile', {
    url: "/profile/:profileId",
    template: '<ion-content class="has-header">' + 
                 '<h3>'+
                   '<button ui-sref="main" class="ion-chevron-left button-clear"></button>' +      
                   'This is the profile ' +
                 '</h3>' +    
                 '<ui-view></ui-view>' + 
              '</ion-content>'
  })
   
  .state('profile.edit', {
    url: "/edit/:field",
    template: '<ion-content class="has-header">' + 
                 '<h3> Nested view to edit profile </h3>' +    
              '</ion-content>'
  })
   
  
  
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
  
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

  
</html>
```